# ISPconfig and running cron jobs as root

Tags: ubuntu, cron

IPSConfig runs cron jobs as root. And when adding new cron jobs in ISPconfig it sets them to also be run as root and I don't see any way to change it. Is this safe?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it safe to be running cron jobs as root when they don't need to be?  That depends; are your cron jobs 100% secure?  If so, then you are 100% safe.  If you aren't completely certain of their security, then no, this is not safe.

This software is ultimately manipulating the standard crontab files.  You can edit these with `crontab -e` and `vi /etc/crontab` .  In the former, every entry is assumed to be for user who's crontab it is (for example, to edit apache's crontab, you would use `crontab -eu apache`).  In the latter, the username comes after the time segment ('* * * * * USERNAME COMMAND')

Answer (score 1):

ISP Config does execute cron jobs in a **jailed** environment, as you can see inside the crontab files created in `/etc/cron.d/ispc*`.

```
SHELL='/usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh'
```

So, execute command in that way should not be a problem if your users can not create unsafe executables (which indeed is not a cron problem).